# Embedded Form Doesn't Show Values in IE

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mailchimp

I've embedded these types of customized mailchimp forms on multiple sites with great success across all browsers, but for some reason, this particular iteration isn't working in IE. The site itself is http://www.buildinggurus.com/ and this form appears on the home page and sidebars of the inner pages.

What happens in IE is the input fields appear as blank boxes. The input value isn't visible, clicking the input field doesn't do anything (read: you can't type into it), and it seems more like a placeholder than a call to action. What am I missing here?

```
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="URLHERE" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="widget-lead-form"><h5>Subscribe to Our Blog</h5>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <input type="text" value="first name" name="FNAME" class="required-name" id="mce-FNAME" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'first name':this.value;" required />
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <input type="text" value="last name" name="LNAME" class="required-name" id="mce-LNAME" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'last name':this.value;" required />
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <input value="enter your email" name="EMAIL" type="email" class="required-email" id="mce-EMAIL" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'enter your email':this.value;" required />
    </div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="clear">
        <input type="submit" name="subscribe" class="submit" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" value="submit" /></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: the ie block of javascript isnt running correctly. put some debugging in there

Comment: The console is complaining "Object doesn't support this property or method". It looks like there's a conflict with the jQuery `$` shorthand, so you need to use jQuery's conflict resolution mechanism.

Comment: I removed the value placeholder text as well as the clear fields. Still not working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

IE still requires a value to be set. The following I use in all of my form input tags:

onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'**default value**':this.value;" value="**default value**"

Comment: The values are all set, though, as corresponding text prompts (instead of default value, the first name field reads "first name," etc.).

Comment: For some reason <value> wasn't working in the text editor the first time around, lol. Do the values display without adding the javascript to the inputs?

Comment: It does in Chrome & Firefox, but not IE

Comment: Any toying/editing is being tested on the "Subscribe to our blog" form on http://www.buildinggurus.com/blog